# How can I prove Proof Irrelevance from Propositional Extensionality in Coq?

Tags: coq

This is a question from "Logical Foundation" in Chapter [ProofObjects](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/ProofObjects.html).

I want to prove that Propositional Extensionality,

```
forall (P Q : Prop), (P <-> Q) -> P = Q
```

implies Proof Irrelevance,

```
forall (P : Prop) (pf1 pf2 : P), pf1 = pf2
```

Input:

```
Theorem pe_implies_pi :
(forall (P Q : Prop), (P <-> Q) -> P = Q) -> (forall (P : Prop) (pf1 pf2 : P), pf1 = pf2).
Proof. intros. assert (H1 := H P True).
assert (H2 : P <-> True).
{ split. intros. apply I. intros. apply pf1. }
apply H1 in H2.
Fail rewrite H2 in pf1.
```

Output:

```
H: ∀ P Q : ℙ, P ↔ Q → P = Q
P: ℙ
pf1,pf2: P
H1: P ↔ True → P = True
H2: P = True
===========================
pf1 = pf2

The command has indeed failed with message:
Cannot change pf1, it is used in conclusion.
```

I understand the line of argument informally in that, with `H2`, both `pf1` and `pf2` are of type `True`. The only constructor for type `True` is `I`, hence `pf1 = pf2 = I`. But how do I prove this in Coq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are rewriting pf1 in one place, but not another. To get everything in the same place, you can use revert. If I have the code:

```
Definition PropEx : Prop := forall (P Q : Prop), (P <-> Q) -> P = Q.

Definition ProofIrr : Prop := forall (P : Prop) (pf1 pf2 : P),  pf1 = pf2.

Theorem PropExImpliesProofIrr : PropEx -> ProofIrr.
Proof.
  intros PE P pf1 pf2.
  assert (H1 := PE P True).
  assert (H2 : P <-> True). { split; intro H2; auto. }
  apply H1 in H2.
```

then my proof state is exactly what you had:

```
1 goal (ID 19)
  
  PE : PropEx
  P : Prop
  pf1, pf2 : P
  H1 : P <-> True -> P = True
  H2 : P = True
  ============================
  pf1 = pf2
```

If I then run the line `clear H1; revert pf1 pf2.`, I get the following proof state:

```
  PE : PropEx
  P : Prop
  H2 : P = True
  ============================
  forall pf1 pf2 : P, pf1 = pf2
```

Now I can rewrite! `rewrite H2.` leads me to:

```
1 goal (ID 23)
  
  PE : PropEx
  P : Prop
  H2 : P = True
  ============================
  forall pf1 pf2 : True, pf1 = pf2
```

Which is easily solved.

```
  intro pf1; destruct pf1.
  intro pf2; destruct pf2.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

For your convenience, here is the entire code:

```
Definition PropEx : Prop := forall (P Q : Prop), (P <-> Q) -> P = Q.

Definition ProofIrr : Prop := forall (P : Prop) (pf1 pf2 : P),  pf1 = pf2.

Theorem PropExImpliesProofIrr : PropEx -> ProofIrr.
Proof.
  intros PE P pf1 pf2.
  assert (H1 := PE P True).
  assert (H2 : P <-> True). { split; intro H2; auto. }
  apply H1 in H2.
  clear H1; revert pf1 pf2.
  rewrite H2.
  intro pf1; destruct pf1.
  intro pf2; destruct pf2.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to abstract again over `pf1` and `pf2` to, thus, be able to perform the rewrite of `H2`, followed by case analysis on `pf1` and `pf2`.